# Как на яндекс карте присвоить меткам рейтинг и вывести их в иконку?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Как на яндекс карте присвоить меткам рейтинг и вывести их в иконку?

1) Метка имеет рейтинг в иконке и цвет в зависимости от балла
2) При уменьшении масштаба иконки кластеризируются по городам, указываю на кластере общий балл города

Поскажите, сталкивался ли кто с подобной задачей?
Подобный функционал есть в карте самоизоляции от Яндекс

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что используется ObjectManager. Тогда нужно определить функцию data для кластера, которая будет пробегаться по схлопнутым объектам и возвращать их рейтинг в качестве веса.

Насколько я понял документацию, реализуется примерно так (`manager` — экземпляр ObjectManager):

```
manager.clusters.events.add('add', function(event) {
    var target = event.get('child');
    target.properties.data = function() {
        return target.properties.geoObjects.map(function(item) {
            return {
                weight: item.properties.свойство_с_рейтингом,
                color: item.properties.свойство_с_цветом,
            };
        });
    });
});
```